# How to Transpose Repeating Columns in certain range to Rows Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a database like this:

| Month | power art | unit | energy_1 (2018) | energy_2 (2018) | energy_3 (2018) | energy_4 (2018) | energy_1 (2019) | energy_2 (2019) | energy_3 (2019) | energy_4 (2019) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | Number of power feeding systems | Number | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 102 | 102 | 102 | 102 |
| Jan | net rated power | MW | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 102 | 102 | 102 | 102 |
| Jan | power feed | KwH | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 102 | 102 | 102 | 102 |
| Feb | Number of power feeding systems | Number | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 102 | 102 | 102 | 102 |
| Feb | net rated power | MW | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 102 | 102 | 102 | 102 |
| Feb | power feed | KwH | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 102 | 102 | 102 | 102 |

But I would get this:

| Month | power art | unit | Energy art | energy_1 | Value | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | Number of power feeding systems | Number | energy_1 | 100 | 2018 |  |
| Jan | Number of power feeding systems | Number | energy_2 | 100 | 2018 |  |
| Jan | Number of power feeding systems | Number | energy_3 | 100 | 2018 |  |
| Jan | Number of power feeding systems | Number | energy_4 | 100 | 2018 |  |
| Jan | Number of power feeding systems | Number | energy_1 | 100 | 2019 |  |
| Jan | Number of power feeding systems | Number | energy_2 | 100 | 2019 |  |
| Jan | Number of power feeding systems | Number | energy_3 | 100 | 2019 |  |
| Jan | Number of power feeding systems | Number | energy_4 | 100 | 2019 |  |
| Feb | Number of power feeding systems | Number | energy_1 | 100 | 2018 |  |
| Feb | Number of power feeding systems | Number | energy_2 | 100 | 2018 |  |
| Feb | Number of power feeding systems | Number | energy_3 | 100 | 2018 |  |
| Feb | Number of power feeding systems | Number | energy_4 | 100 | 2018 |  |
| Feb | Number of power feeding systems | Number | energy_1 | 100 | 2019 |  |
| Feb | Number of power feeding systems | Number | energy_2 | 100 | 2019 |  |
| Feb | Number of power feeding systems | Number | energy_3 | 100 | 2019 |  |
| Feb | Number of power feeding systems | Number | energy_4 | 100 | 2019 |  |

- I can add year column but what can I do with repeating columns in certain range? I try pd.melt but my dataset is repeating.

#pd.melt(df, id_vars=[('Month', 'power art ', 'unit', 'Energy art')], value_vars=[('energy_1', 'energy_2')])

Comment: Try `pd.wide_to_long`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['Month', 'power art', 'unit'])
df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df1.columns.str.extract('(\S+) \((\d+)\)'), 
              names = ['Energy', 'Year'])
df_out = df1.melt(ignore_index = False).reset_index()
df_out

  Month                        power art    unit    Energy  Year  value
0   Jan  Number of power feeding systems  Number  energy_1  2018    100
1   Jan                  net rated power      MW  energy_1  2018    100
2   Jan                       power feed     KwH  energy_1  2018    100
3   Feb  Number of power feeding systems  Number  energy_1  2018    100
4   Feb                  net rated power      MW  energy_1  2018    100
```

Or you could do:

```
df2 = pd.wide_to_long(df, 'energy', df.columns[:3], 'group', '_',
               '\\d \(\\d+\)').reset_index()
df2[['group', 'Year']] = df2.group.str.extract('(\S+) \((\d+)\)')
df2.head()

  Month                        power art    unit group  energy  Year
0   Jan  Number of power feeding systems  Number     1     100  2018
1   Jan  Number of power feeding systems  Number     2     100  2018
2   Jan  Number of power feeding systems  Number     3     100  2018
3   Jan  Number of power feeding systems  Number     4     100  2018
4   Jan  Number of power feeding systems  Number     1     102  2019
```